# bash, extract string from text file with space delimiter

Tags: string, bash, extract

I have a text files with a line like this in them:

```
    MC exp. sig-250-0 events         & $0.98 \pm 0.15$          & $3.57 \pm 0.23$              \\
```

sig-250-0 is something that can change from file to file (but I always know what it is for each file). There are lines before and above this, but the string "MC exp. sig-250-0 events" is unique in the file.

For a particular file, is there a good way to extract the second number 3.57 in the above example using bash?

Comment: When you say "using Bash", do you really mean that sed, awk, grep, etc. are off the table? Or is a shell script that calls out to these tools okay?

Comment: All of those on the table. By bash, I just mean not python, C++, perl, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `awk` for this:

```
awk '/MC exp. sig-250-0/ {print $10}' your.txt
```

Note that this will print: `$3.57` - with the leading `$`, if you don't like this, pipe the output to `tr`:

```
awk '/MC exp. sig-250-0/ {print $10}' your.txt | tr -d '$'
```

---

In comments you wrote that you need to call it in a script like this:

```
while read p ; do 
    echo $p,awk '/MC exp. sig-$p/ {print $10}' filename | tr -d '$'
done < grid.txt
```

Note that you need a sub shell `$()` for the awk pipe. Like this:

```
echo "$p",$(awk '/MC exp. sig-$p/ {print $10}' filename | tr -d '$')
```

If you want to pass a shell variable to the awk pattern use the following syntax:

```
awk -v p="MC exp. sig-$p" '/p/ {print $10}' a.txt | tr -d '$'
```

Comment: This seems to do the trick, is there something I can couple with this to toss out the $ sign at the front?

Comment: Is there a way to escape the $10 so it doesn't get confused with a bash command line input?

Comment: So I'm attempting to run this within a script like this which for some reason doesn't work (but the standalone command works, i suspect trouble with the $10 in bash): while read p; do echo $p,`awk '/MC exp. sig-$p/ {print $10}' /susy/tables/tex/MyYieldsTable_$p.tex.bak | tr -d '$'`; done < grid.txt

Comment: It looks like I need to expand the $p variable within the single quotes, but NOT expand the $10. Because of this, the awk approach can't work.

Comment: Still quite confused, so the final command is supposed to look something like this? : while read p; do echo $p,`$(awk -v p="MC exp. sig-$p" '/p/ {print $10}' /susy/tables/tex/MyYieldsTable_$p.tex.bak | tr -d '$')`; done < grid.txt

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31131/discussion-between-hek2mgl-and-user788171)

Answer (score 1):

More lines would've been nice but I guess you would like to have a simple use awk.

```
awk '{print $N}' $file
```

If you don't tell awk what kind of field-separator it has to use it will use just a space ' '. Now you just have to count how many fields you have got to get your field you want to get. In your case it would be 10.

```
awk '{print $10}' file.txt 
$3.57
```

Don't want the $?
Pipe your awk result to cut:

```
awk '{print $10}' foo | cut -d $ -f2
```

-d will use the $ als field-separator and -f will select the second field.

Answer (score 0):

If you know you always have the same number of fields, then

```
#!/bin/bash
file=$1
key=$2
while read -ra f; do
    if [[ "${f[0]} ${f[1]} ${f[2]} ${f[3]}" == "MC exp. $key events" ]]; then
        echo ${f[9]}
    fi
done < "$file"
```